# iOS Help: How to use camera to take picture and save it on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4

I am new to `iPhone` development. I need to make an App where the user can take a picture and then its saved on the iPhone and also I have to use `SQLite` Database to store the image and later display it.

Can anyone help me with sample code and explanation of the procedure?

EDIT: I made a button that uses an UIImageView to take picture, but I'm not sure if it works because I don't have an iPhone:

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
     UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = 
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *) kUTTypeImage,nil];
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
    imagePicker = nil;
    newMedia = YES;
}
```

The above code uses the front camera

Comment: Shahnawaz - there are any number of tutorials out there on this topic, along with Apple's WWDC videos and even videos on YouTube. Have you made any effort to search out these resources?

Comment: I was looking for suggestions on how to store file path and how to save the picture. I have tried something I didn't know its necessary to show it, but I'll edit the post and show it now.

Answer (score 11):

you can use `UIImagePickerController` class for take a picture..
 you can use following methods for capture image and store it..

```
UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    //put code for store image
 }
```

Comment: @Janak Nirmal  I want the user to have a latest display picture. Is it possible to take new Photo only and prevent Choose existing option ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the examples available on apple's developer library

see these examples

- [AVCam](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112)
- [SquareCam](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SquareCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011190)

and many more reference material is available too.

Happy Coding :)